# javascript alternative to php seralize

Tags: php, javascript

hello I have a javascript array and I would like to use a function for javascript that will take my array and serialize it.

Thanks

Comment: http://phpjs.org/functions/serialize:508

Comment: JSON is another option. Convert the array object into a plaintext representation, which you can then extract into a PHP array `json_decode()` on the server.

Comment: @Marc B, I would personally like to see that as an option for the OP, you should make a post!

Answer (score 2):

The best (native) way to serialize objects in Javascript is [JSON](http://www.json.org/); newer browsers support JSON natively, for other browsers a script can be included:  https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

On the PHP side, there is [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function that can be used to deserialize JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The native PHP function has been ported to Javascript as well in the [php.js](http://phpjs.org/pages/home) library:

http://phpjs.org/functions/serialize:508

Comment: about php's serialized data structure has been said that it should not be relied upon to not change between versions (and it has changed). JSON is a much better option as it has a stable specification and is more portable.